Docker Inline caching not working consistently in Bitbucket pipelines
I have noticed that Bitbucket pipelines are not consistently reusing cached layers during docker build commands and I cannot figure out what is causing a fresh install vs using cached content.
Below is the beginning snippet of the dockerfile:
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.2

FROM --platform=linux/amd64 public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.12.2024.05.22.12@sha256:8b72b07c4eeba48a87799c6357ddf3d0abbd28dd3e0ead220427839cd160121f

RUN dnf install awscli \
    gzip \
    wget \
    tar \
    sudo \
    unzip \
    xorg-x11-fonts-* \
    which \
    cargo \

 ......

The docker build command is
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64 docker build . -t my_image:latest -f dockerfile --cache-from lambda-container:latest --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1

What the entire script that updates the image is doing is that it is creating an image with the name lambda-container:latest and pushing it to AWS ECR with inline caching. I then reuse this image for caching and push a new image with the same tag.
The problem is the first command in the dockerfile:
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.12.2024.05.22.12@sha256:8b72b07c4eeba48a87799c6357ddf3d0abbd28dd3e0ead220427839cd160121f

Sometimes the layer is pulled from cache, but usually it is not, causing all subsequent layers to not use the cache either. Locally, on Mac, cache is always used.
My understanding is that the AWS lambda python layer is static and should never change. Why is cache not being used?
Below are examples of cached and not cached pipeline logs:
CACHE Working:
#1 [internal] load build definition from lambda_dockerfile
#1 sha256:1971d269f37b343c0a956ee760cbe43843934d9b3c4b7c5af66716b026c62b06
#1 transferring dockerfile: 1.74kB done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1.2
#2 sha256:b239a20f31d7f1e5744984df3d652780f1a82c37554dd73e1ad47c8eb05b0d69
#2 DONE 0.6s

#3 docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1.2@sha256:e2a8561e419ab1ba6b2fe6cbdf49fd92b95912df1cf7d313c3e2230a333fdbcc
#3 sha256:37e0c519b0431ef5446f4dd0a4588ba695f961e9b0e800cd8c7f5ba6165af727
#3 resolve docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1.2@sha256:e2a8561e419ab1ba6b2fe6cbdf49fd92b95912df1cf7d313c3e2230a333fdbcc done
#3 sha256:e2a8561e419ab1ba6b2fe6cbdf49fd92b95912df1cf7d313c3e2230a333fdbcc 1.69kB / 1.69kB done
#3 sha256:e3ee2e6b536452d876b1c5aa12db9bca51b8f52b2505178cae6d13e33daeed2b 528B / 528B done
#3 sha256:86e43bba076d67c1a890cbc07813806b11eca53843dc643202d939b986c8c332 1.21kB / 1.21kB done
#3 sha256:3cc8e449ce9f6e0752ede8f50a7334bf0c7b2d24d76da2ffae7aa6a729dd1da4 0B / 9.64MB 0.2s
#3 sha256:3cc8e449ce9f6e0752ede8f50a7334bf0c7b2d24d76da2ffae7aa6a729dd1da4 3.15MB / 9.64MB 0.4s
#3 sha256:3cc8e449ce9f6e0752ede8f50a7334bf0c7b2d24d76da2ffae7aa6a729dd1da4 9.64MB / 9.64MB 0.5s done
#3 extracting sha256:3cc8e449ce9f6e0752ede8f50a7334bf0c7b2d24d76da2ffae7aa6a729dd1da4
#3 extracting sha256:3cc8e449ce9f6e0752ede8f50a7334bf0c7b2d24d76da2ffae7aa6a729dd1da4 0.1s done
#3 DONE 0.6s

#4 [internal] load build definition from lambda_dockerfile
#4 sha256:22bfd75730e4097316b92b393fd63376b422c92ac5252d983cf66cdc3d20fd11
#4 DONE 0.0s

#5 [internal] load .dockerignore
#5 sha256:ace48cd65d1f9e4659afec4d9d50e2a684926260cb7acdea81ad85bc4eba2606
#5 transferring context: 287B done
#5 DONE 0.0s

#6 [internal] load metadata for public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.12.2024.05.22.12@sha256:8b72b07c4eeba48a87799c6357ddf3d0abbd28dd3e0ead220427839cd160121f
#6 sha256:c3df5c18c06d8e17cc6e3c0cdf4b1ca368396536a1e8aad735d34bc34693eb46
#6 DONE 0.7s

#11 [internal] load build context
#11 sha256:edcecccab4067af420405df346052ea6286d9ed758737d6f6109a9255f046b58
#11 DONE 0.0s

#14 [ 1/16] FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.12.2024.05.22.12@sha256:8b72b07c4eeba48a87799c6357ddf3d0abbd28dd3e0ead220427839cd160121f
#14 sha256:cfa005623cedc6e04b3d8640295ecd2e97ce0f3c11cafd4dfd6f3ee41538555e
#14 DONE 0.0s

#25 [auth] sharing credentials for <account_id>.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
#25 sha256:5be2cd302dbd8890816a08d7c38609c114cf8a42b45fb9d69d6ff20ec1ee0b0f
#25 DONE 0.0s

#7 importing cache manifest from <account_id>.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/lambda-container:latest
#7 sha256:7ed802f2cbe433de9324103429b11b5861d65b89926a2624a632bed56c216910
#7 inferred cache manifest type: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json done
#7 DONE 0.3s

#11 [internal] load build context
#11 sha256:edcecccab4067af420405df346052ea6286d9ed758737d6f6109a9255f046b58
#11 transferring context: 9.41MB 0.2s done
#11 DONE 0.2s

#13 [ 2/16] RUN dnf install awscli     gzip     wget     tar     sudo     unzip     xorg-x11-fonts-*     which     cargo     libXinerama     java     nss     dbus-libs     cups-libs     -y && dnf clean all
#13 sha256:bcf275ebe4b4c2951e74585eadb9e12cba634dde9e44ae1db1b314714df4a5c0
#13 CACHED

.......

CACHE NOT WORKING:
#1 [internal] load build definition from lambda_dockerfile
#1 sha256:884e5d7c9f923580f2f2d8955d5ecf6ec4ff7963864aff97cd80ec4ec3ba779a
#1 transferring dockerfile: 1.74kB done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1.2
#2 sha256:b239a20f31d7f1e5744984df3d652780f1a82c37554dd73e1ad47c8eb05b0d69
#2 DONE 0.6s

#3 docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1.2@sha256:e2a8561e419ab1ba6b2fe6cbdf49fd92b95912df1cf7d313c3e2230a333fdbcc
#3 sha256:37e0c519b0431ef5446f4dd0a4588ba695f961e9b0e800cd8c7f5ba6165af727
#3 resolve docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1.2@sha256:e2a8561e419ab1ba6b2fe6cbdf49fd92b95912df1cf7d313c3e2230a333fdbcc done
#3 sha256:3cc8e449ce9f6e0752ede8f50a7334bf0c7b2d24d76da2ffae7aa6a729dd1da4 0B / 9.64MB 0.2s
#3 sha256:e2a8561e419ab1ba6b2fe6cbdf49fd92b95912df1cf7d313c3e2230a333fdbcc 1.69kB / 1.69kB done
#3 sha256:e3ee2e6b536452d876b1c5aa12db9bca51b8f52b2505178cae6d13e33daeed2b 528B / 528B done
#3 sha256:86e43bba076d67c1a890cbc07813806b11eca53843dc643202d939b986c8c332 1.21kB / 1.21kB done
#3 sha256:3cc8e449ce9f6e0752ede8f50a7334bf0c7b2d24d76da2ffae7aa6a729dd1da4 9.64MB / 9.64MB 0.5s done
#3 extracting sha256:3cc8e449ce9f6e0752ede8f50a7334bf0c7b2d24d76da2ffae7aa6a729dd1da4 0.1s
#3 extracting sha256:3cc8e449ce9f6e0752ede8f50a7334bf0c7b2d24d76da2ffae7aa6a729dd1da4 0.1s done
#3 DONE 0.6s

#5 [internal] load build definition from lambda_dockerfile
#5 sha256:eddffe7aad100ec1f895cc22a0de52588db5b4dd09dc4866600d18981c7262c0
#5 DONE 0.0s

#4 [internal] load .dockerignore
#4 sha256:8369df543280e56af0225c380383fff1a04bddc74c7fa45b107bcce289973c2f
#4 transferring context: 287B done
#4 DONE 0.0s

#6 [internal] load metadata for public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.12.2024.05.22.12@sha256:8b72b07c4eeba48a87799c6357ddf3d0abbd28dd3e0ead220427839cd160121f
#6 sha256:c3df5c18c06d8e17cc6e3c0cdf4b1ca368396536a1e8aad735d34bc34693eb46
#6 DONE 0.6s

#9 [ 1/16] FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.12.2024.05.22.12@sha256:8b72b07c4eeba48a87799c6357ddf3d0abbd28dd3e0ead220427839cd160121f
#9 sha256:cfa005623cedc6e04b3d8640295ecd2e97ce0f3c11cafd4dfd6f3ee41538555e
#9 DONE 0.0s

#20 [internal] load build context
#20 sha256:f833d7743bc1eb2fe9a99e59aa592b1622cf367297551b0d059498ceabc70104
#20 DONE 0.0s

#25 [auth] sharing credentials for <account_id>.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
#25 sha256:8a84ff144b467eba56158a1e29e0ef711f5b5fffa70eaf38c0bcd60628330a2d
#25 DONE 0.0s

#7 importing cache manifest from <account_id>.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/lambda-container:latest
#7 sha256:be54d5778a6ba4feb800348adc0ccc71c227fe9760a6671a94a48fab3d88568a
#7 inferred cache manifest type: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json done
#7 DONE 0.4s

#20 [internal] load build context
#20 sha256:f833d7743bc1eb2fe9a99e59aa592b1622cf367297551b0d059498ceabc70104
#20 transferring context: 9.41MB 0.1s done
#20 DONE 0.1s

#9 [ 1/16] FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.12.2024.05.22.12@sha256:8b72b07c4eeba48a87799c6357ddf3d0abbd28dd3e0ead220427839cd160121f
#9 sha256:cfa005623cedc6e04b3d8640295ecd2e97ce0f3c11cafd4dfd6f3ee41538555e
#9 resolve public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.12.2024.05.22.12@sha256:8b72b07c4eeba48a87799c6357ddf3d0abbd28dd3e0ead220427839cd160121f done
#9 sha256:e529a40cc48a589edd1445faaf9803d1e9cae3edce6434fbac8aa92392a6bb9c 0B / 87.99kB 0.1s
#9 sha256:8b72b07c4eeba48a87799c6357ddf3d0abbd28dd3e0ead220427839cd160121f 772B / 772B done
#9 sha256:6cda327d923746c438bcf1d4919bbbc8fb372d64944d4f9e585bb91e0ea26cfe 4.38kB / 4.38kB done
#9 sha256:1d4bba480abe39a1ef90b55caaeac6bd286233142cc1d3843bc65bfebd564c57 0B / 419B 0.1s
#9 sha256:3cd8d539701db04c45d64b3a1a3bc5115ce7f3d47cb96e5e85d69700a8b885c5 1.58kB / 1.58kB done
#9 sha256:9e9459cdc88d52c38a13f6f69d260c8c647acd73278a0666428510ae6ad92bd6 0B / 35.78MB 0.1s
#9 sha256:1d4bba480abe39a1ef90b55caaeac6bd286233142cc1d3843bc65bfebd564c57 419B / 419B 0.2s done
#9 sha256:ca57dfa5425bbe0f80b53bb61c76041aa08a6dfad51e32698fbd67206120cb1e 0B / 2.59MB 0.2s
#9 sha256:e529a40cc48a589edd1445faaf9803d1e9cae3edce6434fbac8aa92392a6bb9c 87.99kB / 87.99kB 0.2s done
#9 sha256:9e9459cdc88d52c38a13f6f69d260c8c647acd73278a0666428510ae6ad92bd6 4.19MB / 35.78MB 0.4s
#9 sha256:6cd4fbfc46ab068cfb6219555fd67ffe82a4a55e62980fdda8c3d0def736c753 0B / 143.79MB 0.4s
#9 sha256:ca57dfa5425bbe0f80b53bb61c76041aa08a6dfad51e32698fbd67206120cb1e 2.10MB / 2.59MB 0.5s
#9 sha256:9e9459cdc88d52c38a13f6f69d260c8c647acd73278a0666428510ae6ad92bd6 9.44MB / 35.78MB 0.8s
#9 sha256:ca57dfa5425bbe0f80b53bb61c76041aa08a6dfad51e32698fbd67206120cb1e 2.59MB / 2.59MB 0.7s done
#9 sha256:8ab7713cccea92a3cb7cdac30fe2abb6cfe6ed8547dfb8348bdfaefd101f5b90 0B / 14.15kB 0.8s
#9 sha256:8ab7713cccea92a3cb7cdac30fe2abb6cfe6ed8547dfb8348bdfaefd101f5b90 14.15kB / 14.15kB 0.8s done
#9 sha256:6cd4fbfc46ab068cfb6219555fd67ffe82a4a55e62980fdda8c3d0def736c753 9.44MB / 143.79MB 1.1s
#9 sha256:9e9459cdc88d52c38a13f6f69d260c8c647acd73278a0666428510ae6ad92bd6 14.68MB / 35.78MB 1.5s
#9 sha256:6cd4fbfc46ab068cfb6219555fd67ffe82a4a55e62980fdda8c3d0def736c753 19.92MB / 143.79MB 1.8s
#9 sha256:9e9459cdc88d52c38a13f6f69d260c8c647acd73278a0666428510ae6ad92bd6 19.92MB / 35.78MB 1.9s
#9 sha256:9e9459cdc88d52c38a13f6f69d260c8c647acd73278a0666428510ae6ad92bd6 25.17MB / 35.78MB 2.4s
#9 sha256:6cd4fbfc46ab068cfb6219555fd67ffe82a4a55e62980fdda8c3d0def736c753 30.41MB / 143.79MB 2.4s
#9 sha256:9e9459cdc88d52c38a13f6f69d260c8c647acd73278a0666428510ae6ad92bd6 30.41MB / 35.78MB 2.7s
#9 sha256:9e9459cdc88d52c38a13f6f69d260c8c647acd73278a0666428510ae6ad92bd6 33.55MB / 35.78MB 3.2s
#9 sha256:9e9459cdc88d52c38a13f6f69d260c8c647acd73278a0666428510ae6ad92bd6 35.78MB / 35.78MB 3.3s done
#9 extracting sha256:9e9459cdc88d52c38a13f6f69d260c8c647acd73278a0666428510ae6ad92bd6 0.1s
#9 sha256:6cd4fbfc46ab068cfb6219555fd67ffe82a4a55e62980fdda8c3d0def736c753 40.89MB / 143.79MB 3.4s
#9 sha256:6cd4fbfc46ab068cfb6219555fd67ffe82a4a55e62980fdda8c3d0def736c753 51.38MB / 143.79MB 4.1s
#9 extracting sha256:9e9459cdc88d52c38a13f6f69d260c8c647acd73278a0666428510ae6ad92bd6 1.0s done
#9 extracting sha256:e529a40cc48a589edd1445faaf9803d1e9cae3edce6434fbac8aa92392a6bb9c done
#9 extracting sha256:1d4bba480abe39a1ef90b55caaeac6bd286233142cc1d3843bc65bfebd564c57 done
#9 extracting sha256:ca57dfa5425bbe0f80b53bb61c76041aa08a6dfad51e32698fbd67206120cb1e 0.0s done
#9 sha256:6cd4fbfc46ab068cfb6219555fd67ffe82a4a55e62980fdda8c3d0def736c753 61.87MB / 143.79MB 4.8s
#9 sha256:6cd4fbfc46ab068cfb6219555fd67ffe82a4a55e62980fdda8c3d0def736c753 72.35MB / 143.79MB 6.1s
#9 sha256:6cd4fbfc46ab068cfb6219555fd67ffe82a4a55e62980fdda8c3d0def736c753 82.84MB / 143.79MB 7.1s
#9 sha256:6cd4fbfc46ab068cfb6219555fd67ffe82a4a55e62980fdda8c3d0def736c753 93.32MB / 143.79MB 7.6s
#9 sha256:6cd4fbfc46ab068cfb6219555fd67ffe82a4a55e62980fdda8c3d0def736c753 103.81MB / 143.79MB 8.6s
#9 sha256:6cd4fbfc46ab068cfb6219555fd67ffe82a4a55e62980fdda8c3d0def736c753 114.29MB / 143.79MB 9.5s
#9 sha256:6cd4fbfc46ab068cfb6219555fd67ffe82a4a55e62980fdda8c3d0def736c753 124.78MB / 143.79MB 10.2s
#9 sha256:6cd4fbfc46ab068cfb6219555fd67ffe82a4a55e62980fdda8c3d0def736c753 135.27MB / 143.79MB 11.1s
#9 sha256:6cd4fbfc46ab068cfb6219555fd67ffe82a4a55e62980fdda8c3d0def736c753 142.61MB / 143.79MB 11.5s
#9 extracting sha256:6cd4fbfc46ab068cfb6219555fd67ffe82a4a55e62980fdda8c3d0def736c753
#9 sha256:6cd4fbfc46ab068cfb6219555fd67ffe82a4a55e62980fdda8c3d0def736c753 143.79MB / 143.79MB 11.6s done
#9 extracting sha256:6cd4fbfc46ab068cfb6219555fd67ffe82a4a55e62980fdda8c3d0def736c753 3.4s done
#9 extracting sha256:8ab7713cccea92a3cb7cdac30fe2abb6cfe6ed8547dfb8348bdfaefd101f5b90
#9 extracting sha256:8ab7713cccea92a3cb7cdac30fe2abb6cfe6ed8547dfb8348bdfaefd101f5b90 done
#9 DONE 15.2s

#8 [ 2/16] RUN dnf install awscli     gzip     wget     tar     sudo     unzip     xorg-x11-fonts-*     which     cargo     libXinerama     java     nss     dbus-libs     cups-libs     -y && dnf clean all
#8 sha256:bcf275ebe4b4c2951e74585eadb9e12cba634dde9e44ae1db1b314714df4a5c0
#8 0.172 Downloading metadata...
#8 6.068 Package                                                            Repository      Size
#8 6.068 Installing:                                                                            
#8 6.068  alsa-lib-1.2.7.2-1.amzn2023.0.2.x86_64                            amazonlinux 516.2 kB
#8 6.068  amazon-linux-sb-keys-2023.1-1.amzn2023.0.5.noarch                 amazonlinux  24.9 kB
#8 6.068  amazon-rpm-config-228-3.amzn2023.0.2.noarch                       amazonlinux  75.6 kB
#8 6.068  annobin-docs-10.93-1.amzn2023.0.1.noarch                          amazonlinux  94.1 kB
#8 6.068  annobin-plugin-gcc-10.93-1.amzn2023.0.1.x86_64                    amazonlinux 908.1 kB
#8 6.068  avahi-libs-0.8-14.amzn2023.0.12.x86_64                            amazonlinux  70.1 kB
#8 6.068  awscli-2-2.14.5-1.amzn2023.0.1.noarch                             amazonlinux  11.2 MB
#8 6.068  binutils-2.39-6.amzn2023.0.10.x86_64                              amazonlinux   4.6 MB
#8 6.068  cairo-1.17.6-2.amzn2023.0.1.x86_64                                amazonlinux 700.7 kB
#8 6.068  cargo-1.68.2-1.amzn2023.0.5.x86_64                                amazonlinux   5.0 MB
#8 6.068  chkconfig-1.15-2.amzn2023.0.2.x86_64                              amazonlinux 165.1 kB
#8 6.068  cpio-2.13-13.amzn2023.0.3.x86_64                                  amazonlinux 278.7 kB
#8 6.068  cpp-11.4.1-2.amzn2023.0.2.x86_64                                  amazonlinux  10.7 MB
#8 6.068  cracklib-2.9.6-27.amzn2023.0.2.x86_64                             amazonlinux  84.3 kB
#8 6.068  crypto-policies-scripts-20220428-1.gitdfb10ea.amzn2023.0.2.noarch amazonlinux  82.0 kB
#8 6.068  cryptsetup-libs-2.6.1-1.amzn2023.0.1.x86_64                       amazonlinux 501.2 kB
#8 6.068  cups-libs-1:2.3.3op2-18.amzn2023.0.7.x86_64                       amazonlinux 271.5 kB

.......


Are you using multi-stage builds? Is there a pattern when the cache does not work? Please share the relevant bitbucket-pipelines.yml fragment with your docker build, push & pull instructions!

You may be facing this docker bugs https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1981 https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/2274 https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/2279

@N1ngu Atlassian support told me my issue is related to a known bug with an open ticket here: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-23193. I can rerun the same exact pipeline over and over from the UI and most of the time there is no caching, but once in a while, layers are being used from cache. But nothing has changed in my dockerfile or the script that builds and pushes the image between each rerun, and there is no pattern that I can see.
